# Debatching Xml Records into set of two using Xpath in Orchestration

Tags: xml, xpath, schema, biztalk

I have referred to [Looping around elements of a message](http://blog.eliasen.dk/2006/11/05/LoopingAroundElementsOfAMessage.aspx) article for debatching however I have little different scenario here wherein I want to split order records in the set of two.

Here is my XML:

[image: Input Order XML]

I want some thing like Order record of Id with 1 and 2 into one file order Id with 2, 3 into second file and last order into third file.

I tried to implement position function but somehow that's not working for me.

Comment: Please post your XML as text, rather than an image.  Also please add expected output, and what you have tried so far that hasn't worked..  Also did you mean 3&4 into second file, rather than 2&3?  Also you say two sets, but there are three sets, please clarify

Answer (score 0):

Usually when there is a requirement to debatch and then rebatch, you either need to use a scatter gather pattern, which can be quite complex to implement

or

I tend to use a database table, I just bulk insert all the records from the payload there, then have a separate process that polls that table using a stored procedure that then returns a payload contain the rebatched records.

Answer (score -1):

U can use the document and envelop schemes and set the body xpath and set the count 2 in the document schema .. this way the receive pipeline with XML disassembler will split the messages.

if you need more logic in splitting u can loop them in an Orchestration or Map using a group by XSLT.

Comment: The set the count to two will not work, so far as I know that trick only seems to work with Flat File schemas